# Which ML method would be best for deriving a rough formula for prediction based on existing data?

Tags: machine-learning

Which ML method would you say is the easiest to derive a mathematical formula from based on already existing data of predictor stats and outcome?

I have this data:

**Opponent 1**:

- Strength: *x*
- Battle Score: *y*

I also have a model that I put against the opponent:

**Opponent 2**:

- Strength: *z*
- Battle Score: *k*

Finally, all outcomes of fights are written into a database (which currently has around 2800 outcomes) and look something like this model:

**Fight**:

- Strength: x - z
- Battle Score: y - k
- Outcome: win/lose

I would want to get proper weights for Strength and Battle Score, so I can derive a simple formula from it and thus somewhat predict whether the next fight will be won or lost.

Comment: Linear regression will do the job here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want "the easiest" for "a simple formula", then for sure it will be a linear regression on the battle score, or a logistic regression on "win/lose". That way you'll have the coefficients of the model, and they will be interpretable (which you won't get from a neural network with hundreds of parameters).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do binary classification. Here is how in Keras:

1. Organize your dataset so that it looks like a *matrix* or a **pandas** *dataframe*:

[image]

2. **Outcome** is going to be the *label* vector and the matrix without fight id and Outcome is going to be the *features* of the dataset.
3. Divide the dataset in train and test, for example with `scikit learn` `train_test_split`
4. Build a simple model with *Keras*

   ```
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.2))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
   model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']
   ```
5. Train it:

   ```
   model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs= 2, batch_size = 500, validation_data = (test_x, test_y))
   ```

Comment: I don't think a neural network with four layers, including a dropout, is "the easiest to derive a mathematical formula".